# Space between html5 elements

Tags: html, space, element

Okay so I'm trying to start from scratch building this html5 site with css, I've tried hard to eliminate the spaces between all the elements: header, nav, article, and footer

They all stay there. I know it's a very basic question but I've spend some time on it and still can't figure what's going on.

Any ideas how do i remove it?

(IF YOU COPY AND SAVE THESE FILES YOU'LL SEE VERY CLEARLY THE SPACE)

Thank you

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My first website</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wraper">
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Inicio
            </li>
            <li>
                Conceito
            </li>
            <li>
                Fotos
            </li>
            <li>
                Informações
            </li>
            <li>
                Contato
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
        <p>
            Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum 
            abc Lore ipsum bdede Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum 
            Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum 
            abc Lore ipsum bdede Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum 
            Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum 
            abc Lore ipsum bdede Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum.
        </p>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <p>Rua B, Lote 16, Vila Dom Pedro I, Paraty</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #F2E8BD;
}

.wraper {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #CCC49F;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav, header, footer {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    }

header{
    background-color: #F0F;
}   

nav{
    background-color: #08A;
}

nav li{
    display: inline;
}

article {
    background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You eliminated all margins on the wrapper containers, but not on the respective content like `<p>` and `<h1>`.

To remove all spaces, just add this (or something similar) to the CSS:

```
h1 { margin: 0 }
p { margin: 0 }
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xE6s/)

Comment: @DaviTrindade If an answer solved your problem, please accept that answer (see the checkmark in the top left of the answer). That way you signal to others, that this was the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you explore the resulting HTML file through a browser's debug tools, you'll see that they have margin CSS values. The header, for example, has `21px` top and bottom on Safari.

Change your CSS to remove this padding - for example, for the header:

```
header, header h1 {
    background-color: #F0F;
    margin: 0
}
```

Out of topic, but are `header`, `footer` and `nav` really valid HTML5 element names?

Comment: The margin on the wrapper elements is removed in the CSS. And yes, all the elements you mentioned are valid HTML5 tags. See, e.g., [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document).